# how to change display/font size in WhatsApp Destop (the Microsoft Store version)

Tags: windows-10, whatsapp

Following the title of this question, I point out again that I refer to WhatsApp Desktop app in its **Microsoft Store version** (not the older one, as downloaded from WhatsApp).

How can I change the display and/or font size in this app (Win 10)?

I've tried scrolling with the mouse when the CRTL key is pressed.
I've also tried holding the CTRL key and pressing the "+" key.

Comment: This might be a usable workaround https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-size-of-text-in-windows-1d5830c3-eee3-8eaa-836b-abcc37d99b9a

Comment: @Gantendo thanks for the reply! this is a nice way of making the text and the display bigger in Windows, but I need to do this only for the WhatsApp Desktop app, not for the entire OS...

Comment: This is one more app designed/implemented by mentally challenged. Not much can be done beyond staying away.

Comment: I switched to using the Web version. In the Web browser I am able to zoom in. A decent workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the problem I've been having, and the simple answer is that you can't.  The only way to increase the font size in the new Whatsapp is to increase - unnecessarily and pointlessly - the font size for everything on your PC.  It's ridiculous that the older version supported changing font sizes, and the new one does not.  After the new version was forced on me, I managed to redownload an older version, and despite the fact that it's glitchy and shows as "outdated", I'll keep using it as long as possible.  The new version is useless to me - even with my reading glasses on, I struggle to read the text unless I increase the font size for the computer through the accessibility settings, which affects everything else negatively.  I won't be using it once the update is finally forced on me, it's no longer fit for purpose for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I switched to using the Web version. In the Web browser I am able to zoom in. A decent workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I accidently found out that now it is possible to change the font size of WhatsApp desktop version of Microsoft store. Finally they added this!
Simply scroll your mouse up and down while holding the CTRL key pressed and you will see the magic. "Code 6", everyone. ;-)